# Checking Palindromes using an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, palindrome

The object is to take a phrase entered by the user and tell them whether it is a palindrome or not. It must have an array and a method. I am having trouble with my array and the return result for my method. I have edited it some but I am still having trouble with the boolean part. No matter what I enter I am getting false. I would also like to make sure that if there was any spaces entered that they would be removed. I have tried the replaceAll but could not get that to work. Thank you for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class palindrome {

public palindrome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int another=1;
            boolean results;

            System.out.println("Please enter a phrase to be checked:");
            String input = keyboard.next();
            if (checkpalindrome(input))
                System.out.println("Yes, the phrase is a palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println("No, the phrase is not a palindrome");

            System.out.println("Would you like to try another one? \"1 or 0\"");
            another = keyboard.nextInt();

}
public static boolean checkpalindrome(String input){


    char array2 = 0;
char[] array1 = input.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());

for(int i=0; i<array1.length/2; i++)
{
    array2 = array1[i];
    array1[i]=array1[array1.length-1-i];
    array1[array1.length-1-i]=array2;
}

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(array1);
System.out.println(test.equals(array1));

return(input.equals(array1));

}
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Aside from the fact that `checkpalindrome` doesn't do anything.

Comment: `checkpalindrome(input)` supposed to return a boolean, checking `if(true)` will always be `true`, you probably want to do something like: `if (checkpalindrome(input))...`

Comment: The code that starts on line `char[] array1 = new char[80];` and till the end is not inside any method - it won't compile

Comment: not sure if in java negative array indexes are a thing, but if they are, shouldnt all negative array indexes but the middle letter in an odd sequence equal their (positive counterparts - 1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also to check if the string is palindrome or not.

```
public static boolean pallindrom(String S)
{
    char arr[] = S.toCharArray();

    int flag = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < (arr.length+1)/2 ; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != arr[arr.length-1-i])
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```